# Spring Data JPA - count number or results of query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to get the **number of results of a query** in Spring Data Jpa, using a **non-native** `@Query` method. It consists of a basic group by plus a having clause.

My plain query looks like this (analogous example):

```
select count(*) from (
    select 1 from table t 
    where t.field_a = 1
    group by t.id
    having count(*) = 2) a;
```

Since Hibernate 5 does not allow subqueries in the `form` clause, I have to find a workaround for that. The only one I found is very inefficient as per the query plan:

```
select count(*) from table t
where t.field_a = 1 and
2 = (select count(*) from table temp where temp.id = t.id);
```

Is there a way to write a Spring Data JPA query that's as efficient as the first one? I can think of no solution rather than selecting the inner query and taking its `size()` in java, but that can produce issues due to a ton of redundant data passing through the network.

Comment: Just write the query as a native query and it will be executed as such.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am looking specifically for a non-native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution to `count` the results of a subquery in JPA but the a workaround is proposed here https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2012/06/counting-rows-returned-from-jpa-query.html.
The principle is to build a native query based on the initial Jpa subselect query.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job if you accept to count the elements in java !

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
    "select 1 from table t where field_a = 1 " +
            "group by t.id having count(*) = 2");

int count = q.getResultList().size();
```

(performances depending on the number of lines returned, but the projection is very light : `1`)

Comment: I actually need to *not* fetch anything more than a number in code.

Comment: and, in your case, do you tkink that the number of lines of "1" (giving the expected count in the end) will be very high ? 200,  2000,  more than 10 000 ?

Comment: yes, I'm expecting results as long as 100,000

Comment: there is a workaround here (although not very pleasant) : https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2012/06/counting-rows-returned-from-jpa-query.html. It eventualy builds a native query based on the first Jpa subselect query.

Comment: seems like what's there in the link would be the best available option. Can you add it as a response so I can approve it?